# Equivariant perverse sheaves and orbit stratification

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, rt.representation-theory, sheaf-theory, perverse-sheaves

Let $X$ be a complex algebraic variety with an action of a connected algebraic group $G$.
The forgetful functor from the category of $G$-equivariant perverse sheaves on $X$ to the category of perverse sheaves on $X$ is fully faithful, and its image is contained in the subcategory of perverse sheaves which are constructible with respect to the orbit stratification (see [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/384534/160416)).

> Under what condition is it the case that every that constructible with respect to the orbit stratification is equivariant?

I know that this is the case, for example, for the action of $G(\mathbb{C}[[t]])$ on the affine Grassmannian of a reductive group $G$ (this is proposition 2.1 in [MV]).

[MV] *Mirković, I.; Vilonen, K.*, [**Geometric Langlands duality and representations of algebraic groups over commutative rings**](https://doi.org/10.4007/annals.2007.166.95), Ann. Math. (2) 166, No. 1, 95-143 (2007); erratum ibid. 188, No. 3, 1017-1018 (2018). [ZBL1138.22013](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1138.22013).

Answer (score 8):

There is a monodromy action of $\pi_1(G)$ on every $G$-constructible perverse sheaf. It must be trivial for equivariant sheaves.

Simplest example is $\mathbb{C}^*$ acting on $\mathbb{C}$. In the description of perverse sheaves as representations of a quiver with two vertices and two arrows $u$ and $v$ the monodromy acts by $(1-uv)$ and $(1-vu)$ on each vertex.

Comment: Is this a sufficient condition for equivariance, or only necessary?